# How do you keep yourself updated with latest technology trends, considering that technology today is enhanced almost every day?

Tags: information-theory

It's most asked question in IT job interview so I want to know what should the way that I explain the answer of this type of question asked to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really not about programming, but about personal technique....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"One machine can do the work of fifty ordinary men. But, No machine can do the work of one extraordinary man"**

The simple meaning of new technology is to make work or effort simpler or make it easy.

Not just technology but everything that may changes you update yourself with it.

To keep updated with technology you need to use technology, specially latest enhanced technology.

The concept is: by doing so (using technology) it will become obligatory for you to keep track of any new or emerging technologies through reading, searching etc.

I am not claiming that this is something you should do. Its one of the way what you try to do to make yourself updated to some extend with the pace of technology change.

you should go and subscribe yourself to various RSS feeds, go frequently to some great sites (dzone, javalobby etc.) and look for blogs/articles which deserves a read.

Things which you don’t know in this case deserves more read and i start googling stuff to get more details.

see, technology products will not succeed if they are developed for their own sake, nor simply to help users complete a specific task. Technology products succeed when they are incorporated by users into their daily lives in ways that serve their fundamental needs as people - fundamental needs such as relating to others and keeping in touch, even when they are miles apart.

The truth is nobody fully understands knows how today’s technology might be used tomorrow. If the recent past is anything to go by it’s likely that people will certainly find innovative and as yet unthought-of ways to communicate and keep in touch.

Thanks,...!!!